# Android - Camera2 - Turn off pre flash

Tags: android, camera2

I am trying to build an app that take picture with red eye. I am using Camera2 capture request as CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON_ALWAYS_FLASH. I noticed that while taking picture, pre flash seems happening in the camera and it reduce the red eye in the picture. How can I turn off the pre flash?