# Disable Pre Flash - Android Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera2

I wanted to know if there is any way to disable the pre-flash that happens when using the Android camera (with flash set to FLASH_MODE_SINGLE). I saw that this question had been asked in a previous question, but there are no answers or even comments.

[Android - Camera2 - Turn off pre flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334110/android-camera2-turn-off-pre-flash)

I thought, perhaps, this question might have a known solution by now.  It would also help to know with certainty whether this cannot be done. Here is the code I am using:

`private void setFlash(CaptureRequest.Builder requestBuilder) {
        if (mFlashSupported) {
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_MODE, CameraMetadata.CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON);
            requestBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);
        } else {
            //error message here
        }`
    }

Answer (score 0):

The pre-flash is generally required to ensure the main flash is fired at the right power level.  Otherwise it may over-expose the scene badly.

If you want to just fire the flash and see what happens, switch AE_MODE to just AE_MODE_ON, and then set FLASH_MODE to FLASH_MODE_SINGLE for one capture request.  The flash should fire for that one frame, at whatever default power the device uses. The resulting image is likely to be badly exposed.

Comment: In Android Studio I see that it recognizes CONTROL_AE_MODE and CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON, but not AE_MODE or AE_MODE_ON.  Are these interchangeable, or am I missing something?

Comment: Well, I tried using the CONTROL_AE_MODE and setting it to CONTROL_AE_MODE_ON, but it does not get rid of the pre-flash.  Maybe I am setting this up incorrectly.  I added code to the original question so you can see how I am trying to do it.

Comment: Are you using a precapture trigger? If you are, then don't - most of its purpose is for precapture flash.  That said, if you're on a LEGACY-level device, then you don't have direct control over flash in any case, but I suppose I assumed that you weren't.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.  I am using a template code that someone else created, and trying to modify it to fit my needs.  I am looking to see what code might indicate that it is "precapture" verses just "capture."

Comment: Anyway, this line `captureBuilder.set(CaptureRequest.FLASH_MODE, CameraMetadata.FLASH_MODE_SINGLE);` causes it to flash twice.  If I remove this line, it does not flash at all.

Comment: Can anyone please verify if the above works because it is not working for me. Also now that CameraX has released is there any easy way to do this.

Any help in this direction would be appreciated. 

@MKSchmidt did you manage to get this to work?